# map(keyPath) where keyPath is a variable

Tags: swift, swift5, keypaths

```
let arr = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
arr.map(\.0) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Works great. But the below code doesn't compile:

```
let keyPath = \(Int, Int).0
arr.map(keyPath)
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'WritableKeyPath<(Int, Int), Int>' to
> expected argument type '((Int, Int)) throws -> T'.
> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.map` expects a closure with signature `(Element) throws -> T`.

In Swift 5.2, key paths were allowed to be passed in as functions/closures (here's an [evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md)), but **only as literals** (at least, according to the proposal, it says "for now", so perhaps this restriction would be lifted).

To overcome this, you can create an extension on `Sequence` that accepts a key path:

```
extension Sequence {
   func map<T>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) -> [T] {
      return map { $0[keyPath: keyPath] }
   }
}
```

<sup>(credit to: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-power-of-key-paths-in-swift/)</sup>

Then you can do what you wanted:

```
let keyPath = \(Int, Int).0
arr.map(keyPath)
```

Comment: Also according to that same evolution proposal, you could write `let transform: ((Int, Int)) -> Int = \.0` and then `arr.map(transform)`.

Answer (score 0):

The evolution proposal showed how to do it with an operator, but you can also use the same `[]` or `()` syntax whether it's partially-applied or not, because subscripts and functions don't need arguments.

```swift
let oneTo5 = 1...5
let keyPath = \(Int, Int).0
XCTAssert(
  zip(oneTo5, oneTo5).map(keyPath[]).elementsEqual(oneTo5)
)
```

```swift
let keyPath = \Double.isZero
XCTAssertFalse(keyPath[1.0]())
```

```swift
public extension KeyPath {
  /// Convert a `KeyPath` to a partially-applied get accessor.
  subscript() -> (Root) -> Value {
    { $0[keyPath: self] }
  }

  /// Convert a `KeyPath` to a get accessor.
  subscript(root: Root) -> () -> Value {
    { root[keyPath: self] }
  }
}

public extension ReferenceWritableKeyPath {
  /// Convert a `KeyPath` to a partially-applied get/set accessor pair.
  subscript() -> (Root) -> Computed<Value> {
    { self[$0] }
  }

  /// Convert a `KeyPath` to a get/set accessor pair.
  subscript(root: Root) -> Computed<Value> {
    .init(
      get: self[root],
      set: { root[keyPath: self] = $0 }
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
/// A workaround for limitations of Swift's computed properties.
///
/// Limitations of Swift's computed property accessors:
/// 1. They are not mutable.
/// 2. They cannot be referenced as closures.
@propertyWrapper public struct Computed<Value> {
  public typealias Get = () -> Value
  public typealias Set = (Value) -> Void

  public init(
    get: @escaping Get,
    set: @escaping Set
  ) {
    self.get = get
    self.set = set
  }

  public var get: Get
  public var set: Set

  public var wrappedValue: Value {
    get { get() }
    set { set(newValue) }
  }

  public var projectedValue: Self {
    get { self }
    set { self = newValue }
  }
}

//MARK:- public
public extension Computed {
  init(
    wrappedValue: Value,
    get: @escaping Get = {
      fatalError("`get` must be assigned before accessing `wrappedValue`.")
    },
    set: @escaping Set
  ) {
    self.init(get: get, set: set)
    self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
  }
}
```