# With Swift replacingOccurrences .regularExpression, how can you PROCESS each match (for example, each match becomes uppercase)?

Tags: swift, regex, swift5

Say you have

```
    let fixed = t.replacingOccurrences(
        of: #"(?m)"aa[.\s\S]*?bb"#,
        with: ,
        options: [.regularExpression])
```

You pass in the text of a file, let's say.

This will of course find all the long strings "aa . . . bb" within the text.

If we do this ...

```
    let fixed = t.replacingOccurrences(
        of: #"(?m)"aa[.\s\S]*?bb"#,
        with: "WOW! $0",
        options: [.regularExpression])
```

it will replace *each* of the "aa . . . bb" with "WOW aa . . . bb".

If we do this ...

```
    let fixed = t.replacingOccurrences(
        of: #"(?m)"aa[.\s\S]*?bb"#,
        with: "$0 $0 $0",
        options: [.regularExpression])
```

it will replace *each* of the "aa . . . bb" with three copies of *that* "aa . . . bb".

What if we want to replace each of the "aa . . . bb" with an UPPERCASED version of "aa . . . bb"

So conceptually something like this ...

```
    let fixed = t.replacingOccurrences(
        of: #"(?m)"aa[.\s\S]*?bb"#,
        with: "$0".uppercased(),
        options: [.regularExpression])
```

Of course, that is not how `StringProtocol` works, it is meaningless.

Thus, I essentially want to do this:

```
    let fixed = t.replacingOccurrences(
        of: #"(?m)"aa[.\s\S]*?bb"#,
        with: process( ... the actual value of $0 ... ),
        options: [.regularExpression])
```

Where `func process(_ s: String) -> String`.

How do you do that, how do you "get at" the value in that pass of the string protocol (ie, of the $0) and then (say) call a function with it, returning a string to use as the result for that pass?

---

Just FTR, specifically I want to remove all whitespace/newlines from each of the "aa . . . bb". (Example "1 2 3 aa x y z bb 1 2 3 aa p q r bb" becomes "1 2 3 aaxyzbb 1 2 3 aapqrbb"

Comment: How about using Swift's own regex API?

Comment: You can group the (aa)s and (bb)s  `#"(?m)"(aa)[.\s\S]*?(bb)"#` and replace them `with: "$1$2"`

Comment: how are you @LeoDabus !  You may have misread the question ..

Comment: @Sweeper yes, I had no idea there was an overload with a closure - you have absolutely answered the question cheers

Comment: @Fattie “For the record, specifically I want to remove all whitespace/newlines from each of the "aa . . . bb".”

Comment: Ah sorry I clarified what I meant by the example !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Swift regex APIs. There are overloads of [`replacing(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/replacing(_:maxreplacements:with:)) that take `RegexComponent`s. You can pass a closure that takes a [`Match`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/regex/match), and computes a replacement.

Example for uppercasing the matches:

```
let text = "something else aa foo bar baz bb something else"
let regex = /(?m)aa[\s\S]*?bb/
let result = text.replacing(regex, with: { match in
    // you can do whatever you want with "match" here,
    // then return a collection of characters
    match.output.uppercased()
})
print(result)
// something else AA FOO BAR BAZ BB something else
```

Comment: or simply `text.replacing(regex) { $0.output.uppercased() }` or `text.replacing(regex, with: \.output.localizedUppercase)`

Comment: Sweeper - brilliant answer thanks!  Didn't have a clue about the existence of `{ match in`  Massive bounty en route

Comment: @LeoDabus - ah!  `.output` is indeed what I was looking for, had no idea about it.  Where the hell is the doco for that ?!!

Comment: @Fattie Are you talking about being able to pass a keypath to a parameter that expects a function type? [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63764608/5133585). Otherwise, `output` is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/regex/match/output). It just gets the output of the `RegexComponent`. For a regex literal with no captures, it's simply a `Substring`.

Comment: Sweeper - Got it, awesome.  Actually I do have (or would like to have) two captures (to be clear, normally I'd use them like $0 $1 ...) I'm afraid I don't understand how to extract the captures from `match` ... if that's possible ? :O

Comment: @Fattie When there are captures in a regex literal, `output` would be of a tuple type, e.g. `(Substring, Substring, Substring)`. You can get `output.0`, `output.1` etc for the groups. I would recommend checking out the WWDC videos on this.

Comment: Sweeper  - INCREDIBLE! (I was stupidly `match.0` instead of `match.output.0` )  TY so much, golden